# How to synchronize Google calendar with Ubuntu 20.04 calendar?

Tags: 20.04, sync, calendar

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and added my Google account at the very beginning.

Now I'm trying to see Google calendar events in the app "Calendar".
From the description in the app it looks like it should synchronize out of the box, but it's not happening.

I tried clicking "synchronize calendars" and also pasting a Google calendar URL as an "online calendar", but with no success (the latter was asking me about credentials, but when I gave them, asked again and again, with no error message).

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many folks, it starts working after a logout/login or restart.

Try that first.